# Random reads in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to do targeted reads on a Spark DataFrame, when I know the row I am after? I know that you can filter using a condition, but was wondering if there is a faster way?

Comment: If the entry isn't far from the beginning you can use `.limit()`. Another option is to use the inner `RDD`, zip it an then filter by your liked position. However, you need to define your concept of speed.

Comment: Question is __how__ you know.